# razor: returned model is always null in Post

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Say i have this form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-page-handler="Button_Submit">
                    <input value="@Model.test"/>
                    <input style="width: 30% !important; opacity: 0.2; " value="Weiter" class="baseButton" type="submit">
                </form>
```

and this class:

```
namespace skillbased_webapp.Pages.Jobs
{
    [BindProperties]
    public class Skills : PageModel
    {
  
        public string test { get; set; } = "test";

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public void OnPost([FromBody] Skills model)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Then my page looks like this:

[image]

Its a simple input form with a submit button.
If I now hit submit:

[image]

}

My model is null. There is no string on there. Nothing.

THe binding into the view works (as seen in the screenshot).
But nothing is ever returned.

Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to receive the whole `PageModel` as parameter in your OnPost() method? Do you just want to get the new value of `test` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you receive the whole `PageModel` as parameter in `OnPost()` method, From your code, I think you just want to bind the value of test property, So you just need to change your view code like:

```
<input value="@Model.test" asp-for="@Model.test" />
```

Then in the backend, just:

```
public void OnPost()
{

}
```

The test property has bind the new value:

[image: strong text]